# Download a zip file from server using C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, webclient

I'm trying to download a zip file from the server to the client side.

Right now the following method id working when I try on my local machine.

```
string zipPath = Path.Combine(_appSettings.Value.ExportFilePath, zipname);
var uri = new System.Uri(zipPath);
using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.DownloadFile(zipPath, @"c:\tfterm-textform\concepts.zip");
            }
```

But when I try this on the test server I've got the following error:

> Access to the path
> '/entwicklung/tf-term/publish/c:\tfterm-textform\concepts.zip' is
> denied.

**/entwicklung/tf-term/publish/** is the server name. Is this a simple access right problem like the error is suggesting or the path is simply not found as it should be c:\tfterm-textform.

What would be the correct way to download the file on the user's machine?

Any help would be appreciated because I've been looking for 2 days and cannot find a solution to my problem.

Edit:
The file is on a Linux server (accessible trhough "/mnt/TFTERM/exports/", Im' trying to donwload it on a Windows server.
If the path are correct, what are my options to allow the application to access the folder on Windows?

Comment: Looks like the test server is running Linux, so paths look completely different.

Comment: Your code seems ok, furthermore, you are receiving an error of 'access denied' which basically means it is not problem with the url or the request, but problem with the Authentication

Comment: Is your client running on Windows? Or Linux/MacOS?

Comment: Always use `Path.Combine(a, b, c)` for every paths when using different operating systems

Comment: _"What would be the correct way to download the file on the user's machine?"_ - Not using [WebClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-7.0#remarks), to start with. _"We don't recommend that you use the WebClient class for new development. Instead, use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient class."_

Comment: ^^ But anyway: Is it possible to download the file using a simple tool like cURL or even the browser? And second question: Did you check and double-check that `zipPath` is actually what you think it is?

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I forgot to precise but yes the server is a linux and the client is  on windows. I will try with the Path.Combine method for the destination as well then! @Fildor What do you mean? zipPath is set as /mnt/TFTERM/exports/concepts.zip, which is the folder where the file is.

Comment: @Fildor I will try with the System.Net.Http.HttpClient class again as well but I had the same kind of error access.

Comment: `/mnt/TFTERM/exports/concepts.zip` is a mount point on your server's file system. It may _or may not_ be local to it. But WebClient (nor HttpClient for that matter) can work with that.

Comment: You can't use `HttpClient` or `WebClient` to access the file system like that (networked or otherwise). Use the System.IO namespace.

Comment: @mxmissile I see. Is it possible to download the file using Sytem.IO then?

Comment: With the IO namespace technically you would Read the file, not download it.